# C# Use comment when compiling and running code from path at runtime

Tags: c#, path, compilation, runtime, comments

Recently I try to compile and run C# code stored somewhere else. My goal is to **import a .txt file, compile it and run it**. I followed this article on [Simeon's blog](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/) about compiling and running C# code within the program, and everything work well.

Then I try making something a bit more complex by importing the C# code from my computer, so I created a .txt file with the following lines that is store for instance at "C:\program.txt" :
*(the text file)*

```
using System;
namespace Test
{   
    public class DynaCore   
    {
        static public int Main(string str)       
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cool it work !");
            return str.Length;       
        }   
    }
}
```

I do some coding based on the same article and that is my code : 
*(the C# program)*

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DynaCode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\program.txt");
            string bigLine = string.Empty;
            foreach(string s in lines)
            {
                bigLine += s;
            }
            string[] finalLine = new string[1] { bigLine };
            CompileAndRun(finalLine);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void CompileAndRun(string[] code)
        {
            CompilerParameters CompilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
            string outputDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
            CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
            CompilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
            CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

            string[] references = { "System.dll" };
            CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerResults compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, code);

            if (compile.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                string text = "Compile error: ";
                foreach (CompilerError ce in compile.Errors)
                {
                    text += "rn" + ce.ToString();
                }
                throw new Exception(text);
            }

            Module module = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetModules()[0];
            Type mt = null;
            MethodInfo methInfo = null;

            if (module != null)
            {
                mt = module.GetType("Test.DynaCore");
            }

            if (mt != null)
            {
                methInfo = mt.GetMethod("Main");
            }

            if (methInfo != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(methInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { "here in dyna code. Yes it work !!" }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This work well, and I got the following output as expected :

```
Cool it work !
33
```

*Note that I put all the code of the .txt file in one big line that I do myseft, because as Simeon said :*

> CompileAssemblyFromSource consumes is a single string for each block (file) worth of C# code, not for each line.

*Even now this sentence still a bit obscure for me.*

( I tried `CompileAndRun(new string[1] { lines.ToString() });` before but there was an error when compiling the .txt file, that's why I do the big line myself. )

**And here is my problem** : I ask myself : "What if I **add a comment** in my .txt file ?", so I edit it and that how it look : *(the text file)*

```
using System;

namespace Test
{   
    //This is a super simple test
    public class DynaCore   
    {
        static public int Main(string str)       
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cool it work !");
            return str.Length;       
        }   
    }
}
```

And of course I got an error (**CS1513**) because I convert the .txt file in one big string, so **everything after the `//` is ignored**. So how can I use comment using `//` inside my .txt file and got the program work ?

I also try `CompileAndRun(lines);`, but after launching the program it crash when compiling the .txt file because of the exception.

I do some search about it and I didn't find anythings about comment. I guess there is somethings wrong about passing only one big line in the CompileAndRun method, but passing several lines don't work as I say upper.
*(Another note : Comment using `/* insert comment */` works.)*

Comment: You can't. Everything on the same line after the double slash is a comment. The only way around that is to use the /* */ or to insert a new line. Your code can contain multiple lines in a single string, you don't need one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element given to `CompileAssemblyFromSource` is supposed to be a file, not a single line of code. So read the whole file into a single string and give it to the method and it'll work just fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var code = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\program.txt");
    CompileAndRun(code);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void CompileAndRun(string code)
{
    CompilerParameters CompilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
    string outputDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

    CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
    CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
    CompilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
    CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

    string[] references = { "System.dll" };
    CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerResults compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, code);
    // ...
}
```